# Rstudio won't produce plots: Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, device

I've seen this error reported several times but there's never been a solution. I'm using Rstudio for desktop in a Windows 10. I'm not able to produce plots in Rstudio. Plots in R command line work perfectly; in Rstudio if I open a device like in `png("myplot.png"); plot(1); dev.off()`, that works perfectly.

But if I just want to produce a plot in Rstudio (like plot(1) for example), I get the following error:

```
Error in plot.new() : 
 Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgfCSkE/c79b28dca0464804b619980ea7a4d95e.png", :
 unable to open file 'C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgfCSkE/c79b28dca0464804b619980ea7a4d95e.png' for writing
2: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgfCSkE/c79b28dca0464804b619980ea7a4d95e.png", :
 opening device failed
3: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgfCSkE/c79b28dca0464804b619980ea7a4d95e.png", :
 unable to open file 'C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgfCSkE/c79b28dca0464804b619980ea7a4d95e.png' for writing
4: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgfCSkE/c79b28dca0464804b619980ea7a4d95e.png", :
 opening device failed
```

I tried unistalling RStudio and R, cleaning the registry, and installing again but still the same. This happened after installing R and Rstudio in a new machine. Never had this problem with Rstudio at Windows 10 before.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I can't find any useful hints anywhere.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
> capabilities()
 jpeg png tiff tcltk X11 aqua http/ftp sockets libxml fifo cledit iconv NLS profmem cairo ICU 
 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
long.double libcurl 
 TRUE TRUE
```